# FirebaseRecyclerView not working inside fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase

Code Inside OnCreateView

```
contactList = v.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        contactList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        contactList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Log.i("UID",UID);
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("contacts").child(UID).child("contact").limitToLast(50);

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ContactModel>()
                .setQuery(query, ContactModel.class)
                .build();


        contactList.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(options,getActivity()));
```

Code Inside Adapter Class

```
 public class ContactsAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ContactModel, Contacts.ViewHolder> {
        Context c;

        public ContactsAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ContactModel> options, Context c) {
            super(options);
            this.c = c;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position, ContactModel model) {

        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.private_chat_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }
}
```

There's no problem with the reference. I use the same reference in an activity class and it works.

Also i was also using the old version of firebase recyclerview. It was working fine. So where can be the problem..

Comment: What if you try changing `parent.getContext()` to `(c)`. The context is `c`?? Try that and tell me!

Comment: Same problem. Now i tried adding Log.I inside onCreateViewHolder. But it's not called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `adapter.startListening();` before `setAdapter` method fixed the problem for me.